# hiding a previous input button

Tags: jquery, hide, this

I have php code which executes a loop, inside which it generates the following:

```
echo "<input type=\"button\" event='$eventID' id=\"sendsomeone\" value=\"Send a family member\"/>";
echo "<span id='$eventID'></span>";
```

Later, I have javascript which follows:

```
$('input:button').click(function() {
   $(this).next("span").append('You clicked this button!'); 
}
```

**This code works fine.  But I want it to also hide the button (*but not all the buttons on the page*)**

I've tried fooling with code like

```
$(this).parent("input").hide();
```

and `$(this).prev("input").hide();`

But I can't puzzle out how to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're already in the buttons selector by using `$('input:button')`, so have you tried doing this?

```
$(this).hide();
```

Comment: one of these days, I'll no longer be Cargo Cult Programming, and I'll know these incredibly simple things.  Wow,  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to look at [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) which is helpful as it swill hide it if it's visible, and show it if it's not:

```
$(this).toggle();
```